# Mensagens Firebase em Portugues

Tags: android, firebase

Fiz o cadastro de usuários pelo Firebase e após a realização do cadastro é enviado para o e-mail para o usuário validar o acesso. Porém, as mensagens do Firebase estão em Inglês. Existe a possibilidade para ficar em português essas mensagens?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer a customização de mensagens através do console do `Firebase`.

Tais alterações podem ser feitas nas opções abaixo:

- Verificação de e-mail
- Redefinição de senha
- Alteração de e-mail
- Verificação por SMS

Para configurar seu projeto do `Firebase` de forma que ele use um gerenciador personalizado de ações de e-mail siga as instruções abaixo:

1. Abra seu projeto no Firebase console.
2. Vá para a página Modelos de e-mail na seção `Auth` da sua aplicação.
3. Em qualquer uma das entradas Tipos de e-mail, clique no ícone de
   lápis para editar o modelo de e-mail.
4. Clique em Personalizar URL acionável e especifique o URL do
   gerenciador personalizado de ações de e-mail.

Para mais informações acesse: [Criar gerenciadores de ações de e-mail personalizados](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)

Answer (score 2):

A solução foi adicionar na Action URL **lang=pt**